# Scrape the financial reports in Yahoo finance

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance

I tried to scrape the quarterly financial reports (income statement, balance sheet and cash flow statement) for >500 companies via Yahoo Finance. The problem I face is that the scrapers yahoofinancials or yahoo_fin retreive values which are incorrect.

E.g. for the ticker 'ABB', they retreive an EBIT of CHF 512'000'000 on the 31.12.2020. However, on [the company's page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABB/financials?p=ABB), the respecitve EBIT is CHF 299,000 k.

Did anybody else experience the same issues and find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out a package called [yahooquery](https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com).  Disclaimer:  I am the author of the package.

```
from yahooquery import Ticker

t = Ticker('ABB')
df = t.income_statement(frequency='q')
df[['asOfDate','EBIT']]
```

```
         asOfDate            EBIT
symbol                           
ABB    2019-12-31   663,000,000.0
ABB    2020-03-31   427,000,000.0
ABB    2020-06-30   615,000,000.0
ABB    2020-09-30  -260,000,000.0
ABB    2020-12-31   299,000,000.0
ABB    2020-12-31 1,081,000,000.0
```

Also, to retrieve all of the financial reports for one symbol in one request, do the following:

```
df = t.all_financial_data('q')
```